# Setting the combo box edit control as bold in owner draw combo when the listbox item is bold

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, mfc

I have a `CComboBox` derived class where I have added my own bold font:

```
// Get the current font used by the control
const auto pFont = GetFont();

// Populate a LOGFONT structure
LOGFONT sLogFont{};
pFont->GetLogFont(&sLogFont);

// Set it as a bold font weight
sLogFont.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;

m_fontBold.CreateFontIndirect(&sLogFont);
```

This is used in the `DrawItem` event handler:

```
dc.SelectObject(&m_fontBold);
```

It works fine. But, when the combo style is DROPLIST the "selected" item will also show in the bold font (if it is bold in the LISTBOX). Good.

But, when the combo is DROPDOWN (with editable control) and the selected LISTBOX item is bold, it does not show as bold one selected.

Am I making sense?

Comment: Did you trace its messages, to check if the `WM_DRAWITEM` message is actually sent for the edit-box item? The documentation mentions "items". In the drop-list case there is no edit-box, it's a static-like control and WinApi may be smart enough to apply the same drawing as the one for the item being selected. In the drop-down case though it's an actual edit control. I would try calling `GetComboBoxInfo()/CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO` and `WM_SETFONT` for the `hwndItem` member.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou That makes sense, to push the font into the edit control. But where do I add this in my derived combo class? `WM_PAINT`?

Comment: The `WM_SETFONT` message needs not be sent only once, after the Win32 window object (handle) has been created. Therefore I would put it in the `OnCreate()` member - you have to override it, call the ancestor's `OnCreate()`, create the font and send the `WM_SETFONT` message - you can initially try doing it in `OnInitDialog()` to check if this actually works (without modifying the class and then having to revert the changes). Where do you create the `m_fontBold` font btw?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou The `MeasureItem` handler creates it if it has not been created yet. So we only have one instance of the bold font. But, we only want to use the bold font for this edit control when the list box item would be drawn bold (determined from itemdata). Using `WM_SETFONT` sounds like it would only be triggered once?

Comment: I have only used the `WM_SETFONT` msg in `OnInitDialog()`, for edit-controls for which I wanted to use a different font, ie before they get visible. If the control is already visible and you want to change the font, you may need to invalidate/repaint it, in addition to setting the font. Haven't tried it, you can experiment with another edit control to check how it works.

Comment: So the font can be either bold or normal? I guess you will have to capture the `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification and change the font in the edit-box. I'm somehow concerned about the user experience though. The edit-box is meant for the user to be typing in there, and he/she will have to type in an edit-box with **either** a bold **or** a normal font? And this is to be determined by the previous selection? Don't know, I would rather reconsider it.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Fair enough, I take your point. 